# How do i move the images on the w3 school lightbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox, w3.css

I'm still new to this website making, and I'm having trouble with w3 schools [Light box](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp). I'm trying to move the images around but every time I do manage to move them it seems to look worse and worse. I have messed around with the CSS but still can't figure it out.

im trying so that the images look something like this [gallery](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp)but still make it use the lightbox.

source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>alithroughthelens</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="body">
<div id="sideNavigation" class="sidenav"><script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNavigation").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
 
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNavigation").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
</script>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Cuando Sale  el Sol</a>
  <a href="#">Obscurité et la Lumiere</a>
  <a href="#">la  Vie en Couleur</a>
  <a href="#">Vacante</a>
    <a href="#">About Me</a>
</div>
 
<nav class="topnav">
  <a href="#" onclick="openNav()">
    <svg width="30" height="30" id="icoOpen">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
</nav>
 
<div id="main">
<h1 class="header">Alithroughthelens</h1>
<img src="Home/Artist copy.png" alt="" width="5918" height="3945" class="homeimg"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body,{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #B7B7A4;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
 
/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #6B705C;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}
 
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #FFE8D6;
}
 
/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
 
/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;

}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
 
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
}
 
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;

    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
 
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color:#6B705C;
}
 
/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color:#6B705C;
    color:#6B705C;
}
 
/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
 
a svg{
  transition:all .5s ease;
 
  &:hover{
    #transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
}
 
#ico{
  display: none;
}
 
.menu{
  background: #000;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 320px;
  @include border-radius(5px);
 
  #transition: all 0.5s ease;
 
  a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #444;
 
    &:nth-child(1){
      margin-top: 0;
      @include border-radius(3px 3px 0 0 );
    }
    &:nth-child(5){
      margin-bottom: 0;
      @include border-radius(0 0 3px 3px);
    }
 
    &:hover{
      background: #555;
    }
  }
}
.body {
    background-color: #FFE8D6;  
}
.header {
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
    padding-right: 64px;
    position: static;
    left: 41px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6B705C;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
.homeimg {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;    
}
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after { 
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to eachother */
.column {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 24%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #6B705C;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    background-color: #6B705C;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: #FFE8D6;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Caption text */
.caption-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #6B705C;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    color: white;
}

img.demo {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 40%;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.pimg {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.csimg {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.pimgl {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Hey! What do you mean exactly by "move the images around"? Running it in the demo editor should be a good way to play around with the images. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

Comment: you need to post your works to here so people know what you're talking about